# Не вызывается повторно скрипт из документа, вызванного ajax-запросом

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

Есть документ *index.php*, в нём кнопка и контейнер, в который я вывожу ajax-запросом другой документ по нажатию кнопки:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="obj" style="cursor: pointer;">plonk</h1>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="main_1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Ajax-запрос берется из отдельного файла *main_1.js*:

```js
$('.obj').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $.ajax({
        url: 'main_1.php',
        success: function(html){
            $('.container').html(html)
        }
    })
})
```

Который выводит код файла *main_1.php*:

```html
<?php
    echo "<div class='target'><button class='but'>Button</button></div>";
?>
<script src="main_2.js"></script>
```

В этом файле содержится контейнер с кнопкой, по нажатию кнопки, вызывается AJAX-запрос из файла *main_2.js*, который вызывает этот же документ и добавляет к содержимому контейнера то же самое, то есть ещё одну кнопку и скрипт.

```js
$('.but').click(function(e){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'main_1.php',
        success: function(html) {
            $('.target').html($('.target').html() + html)
        }
    })
})
```

Проблема в том, что кнопки работают только до появления третьей. То есть, работает и первая, и вторая, но как появляется третья, скрипт к документу не применяется вообще и нажатия больше не срабатывают, как и любые другие функции. Пробовал отключать кэширование, добавлять к скриптам: "main_2.js?", дабы обойти кэширование, посылать POST-запросом, ставить при $(document).ready() - ничего не сработало.
В чем может быть ошибка, почему не применяется скрипт после этого вызова?
Делаю что-то вроде файловой системы, где вызывается один и тот же php-файл, с содержимым, которое меняется от запроса, поэтому необходимо сделать что-то вроде этого, документ с кнопкой указал для примера, но структура 1 в 1, так же прошу дать замечания по оформлению, может что-то можно сделать более "правильно".
Пример:

[image: Прим:]

Comment: чтоб не разводить флуд, просто скажу, где у вас пропадают обработчики. когда вы делаете $('.target').html($('.target').html() + html), вы добавляете новый html, но в старом убираете все ивенты. попробуйте использовать $('.target').append(). кроме того, у вас в dom несколько раз добавляется main_2.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Проблема в том, что кнопки работают только до появления третьей. То есть, работает и первая, и вторая, но как появляется третья, скрипт к документу не применяется вообще и нажатия больше не срабатывают

Уверен, что это не так. Откройте инструменты разработчика, вкладку Network и наверняка увидите xhr запросы. Вот только немного "волшебные". При первом клике срабатывает подгрузка ок. При втором тоже, а при дальнейших - срабатывают всё больше раз (отправляется 2 запроса, потом 3, потом 4 и т.д.). М.б. ещё что-то волшебное. Проблема в том, что при каждой загрузке `main_1.php` подгружается и `main_2.js` и навешивается событие как на появившийся элемент, так и на уже имеющиеся.

Решений может быть несколько:

1. В js делать отключение событие, а потом включение

   ```
    $('.but').off('click').on('click', function() {
        //
    });
   ```
2. Не подключать скрипт в `php` файле, а подключить его единожды в главном `html` файле и использовать делегирование событий, т.е. вешать обработчик клика на ближайшего родителя, который не изменяется динамически и не подгружается динамически. Зачастую вешают его на `document`. Получается вот так:

   ```
    $(document).on('click', '.but', function() {
        //
    });
   ```